# Additional space using mathbotaccent combined with subscripts

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

Using `lualatex` with `unicode-math` I'd like to define a macro similar to `\vec` producing an arrow *below* a letter (using unicode glyph 0x20EF).

Adding the line

`\UnicodeMathSymbol{"020EF}{\vecunder}{\mathbotaccent}{combining right arrow below}`

in `unicode-math-table.tex` within `/usr/local/.../unicode-math`
I get the desired result using `$\vecunder{a}$`, but `$\vecunder{a}_i$` renders
additional space between the letter and the arrow (`\vec{a}^i` does not).

[image]

How do I get rid of the additional space?

BTW: How could I define the macro within my document? Including `\UnicodeMathSymbol{...}` using `\AtBeginDocument` does not work.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the working of `\Umathaccent bottom fixed` when the resulting math atom has a subscript field. But here's a workaround: the subscript is set to the symbol without the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\vecunder}[1]{%
  \Umathaccent bottom fixed 7\symoperators "020EF\relax#1%
  \vphantom{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\vecunder{a}$ $\vecunder{a}_{i}$ $a_{i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The "workaround" does fine and perfectly fits my needs.